# How to correctly return .NET dates from ASP.NET MVC to Javascript/JQuery

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, json, json.net

I've found a million posts about serializing .NET dates to json.
Yet, I'm unable to get any of those to work correctly.

Here is my serialzier code so far:

```
string javascriptJson = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(result, 
   new JavaScriptDateTimeConverter());
return Content(javascriptJson, "application/json");
```

This returns an unescaped string containing the correct JSON, and looks completely right when viewing it in the browser.
(e.g. dates looks like :     date: new Date(023198928) and as far as my limited javascript skill goes, that is how it should look like)

However, I can not get JQuery to understand this, either I get back a plain javascript string, or it simply fails, I want the deserialized object.

I've tried both $.get and $.getJSON

Ideas ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that even though the response from my service is valid javascript, it is not valid Json.

You can not return "{ date : new Date(24342) }" as it opens up for script injection I guess.
I reverted back to the standard .NET Json serializer and simply parsed the  "\Date(343)\" that it returns..

Answer (score 1):

These are not the mothods you are looking for...

[jQuery.get()](http://api.jquery.com/get/):
*Retrieve one of the DOM elements matched by the jQuery object.*

[jQuery.getJSON()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/):
*Load JSON-encoded data from the server using a GET HTTP request.*

Try [jQuery.parseJSON()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseJSON/) instead:
*Takes a well-formed JSON string and returns the resulting JavaScript object.*

Comment: Tried jQuery.parseJSON() but it throws and complains about unexpected token, however var res = eval(data); works correctly

Comment: Plain JavaScript `eval()` - Nice! It seems I didn't see the wood for the trees. Again... It's strange that `parseJSON()` fails, though. If you have the time, you should find out why - and post it here to satisfy my curiosity ;-)